# hide spinner load after end script

Tags: jquery, html, flask, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to show the spinner the moment the AJAX call starts and hide it the moment the AJAX call ends. The problem is that I can't hide the spinner after the script ends.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```html
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-6">
      <div class="card bg-primary text-white mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">Carica directory</div>
        <div class="card-footer d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between">
          <a id='firstAlimentazione' class="small text-white stretched-link" href="#">View Details</a>
          <div class="small text-white">
            <i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i></div>
          <div id="spinnerLoad" class="spinner-border" role="status" style="display: none">
            <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
$(function() {
  $('a#firstAlimentazione').bind('click', function() {
    spinner = $('#spinnerLoad');
    spinner.show();
    $.getJSON('/firstScript', function(data) {
      spinner.hide()
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: Is your code being hit where your ajax call ends? Have you tried putting a `console.log(...)` in there to find out?

Comment: So long as the AJAX call is successful, the code should work. This either means that the `click` handler isn't being run or the AJAX is failing. In either case check the console for errors. Also note that `bind()` has been deprecated for a long time. You should look at using `on()` instead

Comment: but unfortunately I can't figure out how to make an ajax call the right way

Answer (score 0):

Use success function in your ajax code.